# Cannot expand xargs placeholder for stat command

Tags: bash, shell, xargs

**Intro**

Let's say I have this folder structure

```sh
images/
  image1.png
  image1.webp
  image1.avif
  image2.jpg
  image2.webp
  image2.avif
```

And I want to run through each image and show its respective size in a following format:

`images/image1.png: 12333 | webp: 6300 | avif: 3400`

`images/image2.jpg: 15983 | webp: 8497 | avif: 1248`

I am currently stuck at this attempt:

```sh
find -E images -regex ".*\.(png|jpg)" | xargs -I_ echo 'function getimgsize () { echo $(stat -c "%s" "$1"); }; srcimg="_"; srcimgnoext=$(echo "$srcimg" | sed -E "s/.jpg|.png//g"); srcimgsize=$(getimgsize "$srcimg"); webpsize=$(getimgsize "$srcimgnoext.webp"); avifsize=$(getimgsize $srcimgnoext.avif); echo "$srcimg: $srcimgsize | webp: $webpsize | avif: $avifsize"' | sh
```

The script above yields:

```sh
stat: cannot stat '_': No such file or directory
stat: cannot stat '_.webp': No such file or directory
stat: cannot stat '_.avif': No such file or directory
stat: cannot stat '': No such file or directory
stat: cannot stat '_': No such file or directory
stat: cannot stat '_.webp': No such file or directory
stat: cannot stat '_.avif': No such file or directory
_ :
function getstat () { echo ; }; srcimg=_; srcimgnoext=_; srcimgsize=; webpsize=; avifsize=; echo _ :
```

**Question**

How to fix the script so that it yields the proper results in a proper format?

Comment: The placehold needs to be a separate argument, not a character inside another string which is you case.

Comment: thank you @Philippe

Comment: Aside from this, I would use `find .... -print0` and use the `-null` option of xargs, because maybe one day you will have files with spaces in their names. Also, the whole `echo ... | sh` stuff is pretty unmaintainable and difficult to debug. Write a separate shell script which is invoked by xargs and takes care of displaying the desired properties of the files.

Comment: @user1934428 indeed. For this one tho I wanted specifically a oneliner.

I forgot about the fact that you can pass positional arguments to sh -c,  which saved the day basically.

Oh and I  used print0 for find and -0 on xargs, but for some weird reason it had no affect on my files that DO have names with whitespaces. That's why I posted without.

No idea.

Comment: In this case, xargs will pass the files properly, but the command acting on the xargs execution string must mess up with the spaces somehow. BTW, writing everything in a single line usually does not win you a medal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> ```
> xargs -I_ echo 'function getimgsize ()...
> ```

Ugh, so convoluted. If you find yourself in such a situation, and you are using Bash, it means something is wrong. Just write the function and export it.

```
getimgsize() {
    stuff to do with "$1"
    srcimg="$1"
}
export -f getimgsize
input | xargs -n1 bash -c 'getimgsize "$@"' _
```

Do not write complicated code in single quotes. Use shellcheck to check for common mistakes. Do not use `function name()` - just `name()`. The `xargs stuff | sh` looks odd, I think `xargs sh -c 'stuff'` is commonly preferred. Do not pass arguments inside strings `xargs -I {} sh -c 'echo {}'` - prefer to use positional arguments `xargs -I {} sh -c 'echo "$1"' - {}`. Do not use `echo $(stuff)`. Just `stuff`, it already outputs it.

Is there really any value in using `xargs` here? Just loop it.

```
getimgsize () { stat -c "%s" "$1"; }
find -E images -regex '.*\.(png|jpg)' |
while IFS= read -r srcimg; do
    srcimgnoext=$(<<<"$srcimg" sed -E 's/\.(jpg|png)$//')
    srcimgsize=$(getimgsize "$srcimg")
    webpsize=$(getimgsize "$srcimgnoext.webp")
    avifsize=$(getimgsize "$srcimgnoext.avif")
    echo "$srcimg: $srcimgsize | webp: $webpsize | avif: $avifsize"
done
```

Comment: thanks for your valuable feedback. Tbh I wanted a oneliner for this specific script. I fixed it by passing the argument from outside as you mentioned in your answer. Thanks much

Comment: `I wanted a oneliner` Replace newlines for `;` and you have a oneliner.

Comment: indeed but `xargs` to me reads a little better in oneline than while loop

`xargs -I{} sh -c 'function getstat () { echo $(stat -c "%s" "$1"); }; srcimg="$1"; srcimgnoext=$(echo "$srcimg" | sed -E "s/.jpg|.png//g"); srcimgsize=$(getstat "$srcimg"); webpsize=$(getstat "$srcimgnoext.webp"); avifsize=$(getstat "$srcimgnoext.avif"); echo "$srcimg : $srcimgsize | webp: $webpsize | avif: $avifsize"' - {}`

For a shell script I'd use your while loop tho

But that's the "tastes" land.

Anyways thanks for quick response and have a great day

Answer (score 1):

I have a script similar to this, for comparing different compression formats. Here's a short adaption:

```
find . -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 -type f \
\( -name '*.png' -o -name '*.jpg' \) -print0 |
while IFS= read -rd '' file; do
    file=${file#./}
    name=${file%.*} ext=.${file##*.}
    list=$name

    for i in "$ext" .webp .avif; do
        size=$([[ -e "$name$i" ]] && stat -c %s "./$name$i")
        list+="$i: ${size:--} | "
    done

    echo "${list% | }"
done |
column -t |
sort -k1,1
```

Looks like:

```
dragon.jpg:  111626  |  .webp:  -       |  .avif:  -
foo1.png:    20088   |  .webp:  5000    |  .avif:  295040
foo2.png:    12254   |  .webp:  13320   |  .avif:  74036
foo3.png:    19600   |  .webp:  -       |  .avif:  101388
foo4.png:    160800  |  .webp:  353883  |  .avif:  25792
foo5.png:    397100  |  .webp:  325920  |  .avif:  59249
```

It prints a dash if the corresponding file doesn't exist. You can change the delimiters etc.

Comment: awsm, thanks much